# How to adjust for the baseline difference between groups for a histogram

Tags: data-visualization, normalization, group-differences, histogram, baseline

I have data from an experiment that tested responses to stimuli in females and males. I measured baseline for both groups prior to presenting the stimuli. The baseline for males is higher than for females. The response to the first stimulus is positive for females and negative for males. In comparing the responses between males and females, it would be easier to see the difference if I could adjust the baselines to be equal. What is the appropriate way to do this?

In the histogram below, 0 through 300000 is the baseline period (from the first black line to the first dashed red line). Orange is males, blue females.

Ultimately I have two goals for this experiment: 1) show change from baseline in females and males, and 2) show the difference in this change between females and males.

[image]

Comment: If you are interested in the effect of the stimulus, then why is this not purely a difference in differences (DID) experiment? For each subject, is it fair to say that the effect of the stimulus is the difference with and without the stimulus? (In a "DID" ANOVA the difference in effect by gender may show up as an interaction.) // Alternatively, in a situation where males and females both get the stimulus, you might be interested in the resulting gender difference. // You need to say explicitly what your goal is.

Comment: @BruceET Thanks for your comment. I have two goals: 1) show change from baseline in females and males, and 2) show the difference in this change between females and males. This means that even if I were to lose all the male data, I would still be able to achieve my first goal for females.

Comment: You could use two paired t tests for (1) and 2-sample t test on differences for (2), However with all of that, you might find it more convenient to use a "DID" ANOVA (Factors M/F and Before/After with interaction. // Search 'difference in differences' on this site for several relevant pages.

Comment: @BruceET Thanks for the advice!

Comment: For change from baseline to be meaningful you must have no regression to the mean and you must have perfectly transformed Y.  I suggest you think of sex and baseline measurement of Y as covariates.  A semiparametric model will model how the entire distribution of Y shifts with baseline and with sex, each adjusted for the other, without assuming a distribution for Y.